# Was I being arrogant?

Tags: discussion

I feel somewhat scarred after answering this reference request:

[Historically first axiomatization of the inner product](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/541499/historically-first-axiomatization-of-the-inner-product)

Was I wrong to say that the OP's subsequent comment was arrogant?

Comment: What is the reason for the down-vote?

Comment: No, you were not arrogant. The OP seemed to forget you were doing them a favor. Better move on.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo: thank you! Tomorrow is another day!

Comment: The OP reminded me of the title character in the movie "Arthur".  The proper reply is the one that John Gielgud so famously uttered, and which I will not reproduce here.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

What the OP did was to "look a gift horse in the mouth".

Or rather, after getting a horse without cost, he wants a saddle, shoes, stirrup, reins and food for the horse. It was natural to get annoyed.

But these are all natural wishes.. The OP just momentarily forgot that this is all a freebie. We are human and we have this weakness to want more and more even as our wishes are granted. You can reason like that and forgive/forget about this incident.

Answer (score 19):

One disadvantage of Internet correspondences is that you do not get to hear/understand the intonation of someone else's sentences. For example, suppose that I told you, "You were damn wrong to say what you have said," what do you think my intonation is? Is it a "don't worry about these things a lot man, these things happen, laugh it off" kind-of sentence or a more serious one that carries its exact literal meaning? Given these possibility of ambiguities, both sides should exercise caution. Perhaps, the OP should have tried to be a little more polite to avoid misunderstanding. Perhaps, you should have been not so fast to take it as a form of arrogance. Rather you may have said, "Well, that sounds a little bit offensive, I hope you didn't mean it" or perhaps something a little softer. The OP may have better said: "Library is a little bit far, and I do not have much time, are you sure it is in that book?" or something like that. In any case, you both seem good people, laugh it off man :)

Comment: You are probably being too charitable to me and to the OP. I think I found the right playground metaphor in the end.